# Getting a read access violation trying to spin up a Vulkan instance

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sdl, vulkan

I am trying to use the `vkCreateInstance()` method but I am getting a read access violation from `vulkan-1.dll`. I am using SDL for windowing, and am using Visual Studio 2022, and have both Windows and my graphics drivers up to date

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_vulkan.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

SDL_Window* window;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Video initialization failed:" << std::endl;
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("vkTest", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);
    SDL_vulkanInstance inst;
    VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info;
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "engine";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    inst_info.flags = 0;

    uint32_t vkExtensionCount = 0;
    
    if (!SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &vkExtensionCount, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get Vulkan extensions." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::vector<const char*> vkExtensions;
    vkExtensions.resize(vkExtensionCount);

    

    if (!SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &vkExtensionCount, vkExtensions.data())) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get Vulkan extensions." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << *vkExtensions.data() << std::endl;

    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = vkExtensionCount;
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = vkExtensions.data();

    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;

    VkResult res = vkCreateInstance(&inst_info, nullptr, &inst);
    if (res == VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER) {
        std::cout << "Cannot find compadible vulkan driver." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (res) {
        std::cout << "unknown error" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that your `VkInstanceCreateInfo` does contain uninitialized values. You declare it as `VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info;` without initializing the structure. Later on you only set some members of it to defined values, thus passing uninitialized values to the implementation, which then fails at interpreting them. `VkInstanceCreateInfo` e.g. has a `pNext` member, which is a pointer chain to structures that can contain additional parameters for the instance creation. If this is uninitialized the implementation tries to interpret this as a pointer which will result in a read error.

The correct way would be either setting all members of `inst_info` of zero-initializing it like this:

```cpp
VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info{};
inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
```

In general (not only for Vulkan) you should zero-initialize all structs.